# Could not access Dropbox API via parse cloud code although works with CURL

Tags: curl, parse-platform, dropbox-api, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to access the following end-point from parse cloud code:

```
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account
```

Details of end-point:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#users-get_current_account

My cloud function at the point of making request.

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  }
});
```

Error received from Dropbox:

```
Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack"
```

I then tried using CURL:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account --header "Authorization: Bearer **access_token"
```

This worked and I got the user's data.

Based on the error, I modified the cloud code:

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + newAccessToken
  }
});
```

Now I got the following error:

```
Error in call to API function \"users/get_current_account\": request body: could not decode input as JSON
```

There is no request body in the httpRequest. I then tried setting the body to null and ''. Both gave the same error.

First, I don't understand why the dropbox API requires a `POST` request with no parameters.

Second, how could I resolve the error.

Many Thanks!

----- Update -----

Have tried the other two content types from the error i.e.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack'
```

and still get the same error:

```
Error in call to API function \"users/get_current_account\": request body: could not decode input as JSON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! this worked for me:

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + newAccessToken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(null)
});
```

I had to use `JSON.stringify(null)` in the body.

The link below helped me in identifying the solution:

https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204379696-get-current-account-API-is-strange-and-does-not-work-with-common-sense-

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`, but it can happen that it is sending a default content type parameter with the request body. Whereas, the `curl` doesn't send any default value for content type, that's why probably it is working with you.

From the error msg, I can see it will accept the `text/plain` too, so you can try with that.

```
'Content-Type': text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack',
```

I don't know why they are using `POST` with no incoming data.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all three content types now but still get the same error. Refer to update above.

Comment: It is strange. May be you can try with `-XGET`.